# Using DocuSign API to create an envelope with multiple documents

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently using DocuSign APi to upload multiples envelopes to DocuSign. It's working great when envelopes contains only one document, but i'm facing an issue when i'm trying to upload multiple documents at once.

I'm passing an array of documents to the creates an enveloppe post API, all of them with different names, content and ID and only the first document of the array is imported by DocuSign.

The body i'm sending to the API looks like this :

```
{
      templateId: 7b9b4c21-91db-428a-b405-0f045804c053,
      documents: [
        {
          documentBase64: (the encoded value of the first document in base 64),
          name: 'test first document',
          fileExtension: 'pdf',
          documentId: '1',
        },
        {
          documentBase64: (the encoded value of the second document in base 64),
          name: 'test second document',
          fileExtension: 'pdf',
          documentId: '2',
        },
      ],
      emailSubject: `[Dossier XXXXX ] NAME OF THE PERSONNE `,
      templateRoles: [
        {
          email: test@test.com,
          name: Testname,
          defaultRecipient: true,
          routingOrder: '1',
          roleName: 'EMPRUNTEUR',
          tabs: {
            signHereTabs: [
              {
                documentId: '1',
                height: '60',
                locked: 'false',
                pageNumber: 5,
                required: 'true',
                tabId: 'signature',
                tabLabel: 'signer ici',
                width: '120',
                xPosition: '58',
                yPosition: 360,
              },
            ],
          },
        },
      ],
    }
```

The APi is not sending any errors whatsoever, everything seems fine except that only one document is imported (the first one, doesn't mather if i try to switch up the content of the 2 documents i'm trying to send, only the content of the first matters)

Am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use composite templates if you are trying to use a template AND and additional documents in a single API call.
Alternatively,  you can add the documents later to an existing antelope, but I recommend against it.

JSON looks like this:

```
"compositeTemplates": [
  {
    "document": {...},
    "serverTemplates": [{...}],
    "inlineTemplates": [{...}]
  }
]
```

See how to use composite templates in this article:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/templates/composite/